# How to transmit a signal to a point

Tags: signal, frequency, electromagnetism, transmitter, wave

I have a signal generator (Digital Dual Channel Funktion Signal Generator) and want to generate two signals (530 and 550 Khz signal) and want to transmit these generated signals to the points on a table (see picture bellow) one by one.

I don't know, how a signal generator works. I think, when i generate a signal it transmits the signals to everywhere. But i want to send the signal only to certain points on table.

The distance between the points on table and signal generator is one meter.

Is that possible? if yes, how?

[image: SIGNAL GENERATOR TRANSMITS SIGNALS TO POINTS]

Comment: This is too closely related to your other question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/441862/how-to-move-metal-elements-via-magnetic-waves.

Comment: @Transistor so vote to close as a duplicate, alas I cannot do so having already voted to close for the unclarity.

Comment: Why vote to close? In another topic they have written something else. Now you give that feedback. I can't understand you.

Comment: I also voted to close as unclear, because it's not clear how OP would defy the very fundamental laws of physics. This doesn't have to be a duplicate to be off-topic.

Comment: what signal generator do you have? ... manufacturer, model, maybe a picture

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07593GDB7 this is the product, i can also buy another one, if it will work, what i want

Comment: This and your previous case show you know nothing about electromagnetics except some discrete words and your dreams. Sorry!. Back to school or get a local tutor, that's my suggestion!  A laser beam could be with some mechanism directed as you want, but the wavelength should be 500 ...1000 million times shorter than you wanted in the question.

Comment: Of course i have no idea about EM. If i had, i wouldnt ask such stupid questions here.

Answer (score 3):

Short of running wires either the full way or to capacitive pads or coils at the points in question, this is not possible with electromagnetic waves at your frequencies of interest, because you cannot get the kind of spatial precision you want when the wavelength is so large.

It might with *extreme* effort be possible with ultrasound, or by using two microwave frequencies that would mix in a chosen non-linearity to produce a difference frequency.

But realistically, whatever your unclear goal is, **transmission of low frequency RF signals to particular points in space is the wrong way to try to do it**.